# reverse last and first name and remove comma

Tags: jquery

Is there a way not to us the radio button but execute javascript automatically? 
I see i'm using `.click` function, which command need to be used for execute it automatically? 
Thank you for the advice.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='change_last_first']").click(function () {
        $(".name").each(function() {            
            var revName = $(this).text().split(" ").reverse().join(" ");
            $(this).text(revName);
            });
        });
    });
    
    function name(str) {
    return(str.replace(/,/g,''));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="change_last_first" value="first" type="radio" >First Last, 
    <table>
        <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>         
        </thead>       
         <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="name">Willis, James</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="name">Handson Willis</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="name">Anderson, Sarah</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="name">Pandora, Jim</td>
            </tr>            
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: There are ways, sure, an [`IIFE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) for example, or calling the function automatically in the script.

Comment: @DavidThomast thank you, i tried but it doesn't work.. can you share an example?

Comment: Can you share your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work on load just remove the `click()` handler, and place your `each()` logic directly within the document.ready handler.

That being said, you can improve the logic by providing a function to `text()` which iterates over all elements in the collection. This function accepts the current text value of the element as an argument which you can amend and use to return the new value. Finally you can `split()` the text by comma *or* whitespace in order to remove the trailing comma which is left in some cases by your current code.

With all that said, try this

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".name").text(function(i, t) {
    return t.split(/,|\s/).reverse().join(" ");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td class="name">Willis, James</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="name">Handson Willis</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="name">Anderson, Sarah</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="name">Pandora, Jim</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```